# How to show grid view after Data Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using `GridView` to bind data from database.When i execute the program data will bind in 'Gridview' but the Grid was not shown.But when i get the grid rows `Count` it shows 3.Why it will not be shown.I used this same Grid for store values before and after `Search` Before search(on load) all values will be Bind,But After No changes in Gird...

Code:

```
 gvUserManage.DataSource = dsCandiDeat.Tables[0];
   gvUserManage.PageIndex = PageIndex;
   gvUserManage.DataBind();
   int c= gvUserManage.Rows.Count;
```

Design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserManage" runat="server" Style="border: 1px;" RowStyle-BorderColor="#ebf3e4" 
                                RowStyle-BorderStyle="None" GridLines="Both" PageSize="10" 
                                AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="" 
                                CssClass="grdCandList" RowStyle-CssClass="RowStyle"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AltRowStyle" 
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdheaderCandList" DataKeyNames="UserId" 
                                onrowcommand="gvUserManage_RowCommand" 
                                onrowdatabound="gvUserManage_RowDataBound" 
                                onpageindexchanging="gvUserManage_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="true" 
                                onsorting="gvUserManage_Sorting">
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <div class="shadowbox" style="min-height: 75px;">
                                        <br />
                                        <center>No Data Found.</center>
                                    </div>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdcolumncenter" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 NameHeaderWidth" SortExpression="CandiName">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <h4 style="font-size:13px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal !important; color:rgb(67, 73, 75); font-family:Calibri;"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCandidateView" runat="server" style="text-decoration:none; color:#1382ce;" onmouseover='mouseover(this);' onmouseout='mouseout(this);' CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CandidateId")%>' ><asp:Label ToolTip='<%# Eval("CandiName")%>' ID="lblGrdCandiName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CandiName")%>'></asp:Label></asp:LinkButton></h4>
                                            <div style="float: left;">
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnNewCmnt" runat="server" Visible="false" CommandName="NewCmnt"
                                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CandidateId")%>' ToolTip="New Comment" ImageUrl="~/Images/reminder.png" />
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 PositionHeaderWidth" SortExpression="CurrPosi">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdPosition" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CurrPosi")%>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("CurrPosi")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Experience" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 ExperienceHeaderWidth">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdExperience" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotWrkExp")%>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("TotWrkExp")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Technology" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 TechnologyHeaderWidth">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdTechnology" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SkillSet")%>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("SkillSet")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 StatusHeaderWidth" SortExpression="USStatus">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("USStatus")%>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("USStatus")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 LocationHeaderWidth" SortExpression="Location">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Location")+"  "+ Eval("JobZipCode")%>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Location")+"  "+ Eval("JobZipCode")%>' AccessKey                            ></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Block Resume" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdcolumnheadermiddle pad_left5 pad_right5 SalHeaderWidth">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkResume" runat="server" checked='<%# Eval("ActiveResume").ToString().Equals("n")%>'/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
                                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                                <pagersettings mode="NumericFirstLast" firstpagetext="First" lastpagetext="Last" pagebuttoncount="5" position="Bottom"/> 
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdheaderCandList" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Something mess perhaps with your css styles?

Comment: i use same css style for many grid those grids works fine...

Comment: May be you missed specifying `AccessKey` for asp:label `lblGrdLocation`.

Comment: @HassanNisar 'AccessKey' also used in lblGrdLocation

Comment: i would suggest you to get rid of all the <templatesfields> and try it with only one field and check if its showing up or not. May be some minor glitch. Try debugging the designer page.

Comment: But @PraveenS my point is that you have not specified AccessKey value and its Associated Control ID.

Comment: check any errors in onrowdatabound event

Comment: @Musthaan i checked onrowdatabound there is no error and passing values only binded..but not shown in view.

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Set Access Keys for Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Your code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGrdLocation" runat="server" 
           Text='<%# Eval("Location")+"  "+ Eval("JobZipCode")%>' 
           ToolTip='<%# Eval("Location")+"  "+ Eval("JobZipCode")%>' AccessKey >   
</asp:Label>
```

May be it doesn't solve the issue but this statement could be problematic in your markup.

For specifying `Access Key` for a Label control you have to specify `AssociatedControlID`. For details see MSDN reference above.

Also you must look into `gvUserManage_RowDataBound` event.